# Change Lewis line width using chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I'm drawing chemical molecules with Chemfig and, in the preamble, I defined a 0.8pt width for the lines. However, the line style doesn't apply on Lewis ones...
How can I do to fit them so that they have a 0.8pt width as well?
Here is the code :

```
\setchemfig{bond style={line width=0.8pt}, atom sep=30pt}
\begin{document}
...
\chemfig[line width=4pt]{H-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-C(=[:90]\lewis{13,O})-\lewis{26,O}-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-H}
...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{bond style={line width=0.8pt}, atom sep=30pt}
\begin{document}
\setcharge{|style={line width=0.8pt}}
\chemfig{H-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-C(=[:90]\charge{45=\|,135=\|}{O})-\charge{90=\|,-90=\|}{O}-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-C(-[:90]H)(-[:-90]H)-H}
\end{document}
```

[image]